# invalid_client error with Python OneDrive SDK

Tags: python, onedrive

I am using the OneDrive Python SDK to interact with OneDrive, however the authentification doesn`t work. When running the template code give on the [github page](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python) with my app credentials, i can authentificate the app in the browser and the answer-code gets passed back to my python programm. Then i get an error, saying invalid client.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2016 15:34:42] "GET /?code=Mca303484-04b1-e70c-cfb4-7e902c7a4c9b HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Tim/PycharmProjects/untitled/onedrive.py", line 27, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Tim/PycharmProjects/untitled/onedrive.py", line 23, in main
    client.auth_provider.authenticate(code, redirect_uri, client_secret)
  File "C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\onedrivesdk\auth_provider.py", line 169, in authenticate
    data=params)
  File "C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\onedrivesdk\http_provider.py", line 71, in send
    custom_response = HttpResponse(response.status_code, response.headers, response.text)
  File "C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\onedrivesdk\http_response.py", line 51, in __init__
    raise Exception(str(message["error"]))
Exception: invalid_client
```

I also tried executing the example programm, from the One Drive Python [SDKs GitHub page](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python/blob/master/examples/CommandLineFileExplorer.py). Surprisingly this code/app works without a problem. To my understading, the only real differences are the client_secret and the client_id, which also differ in structure and not just in content.

For example, my client ID is: **3753a627-146e-4137-8f6e-8c561547551b**
while  the client ID in the example is: **00000000481695BB**

I don`t understand why the secret/id are different in structure and why my programm fails, while the example works without a problem.

Comment: Same issue with cloudrail sdk

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the client Value *not* the client Secret ID. This was my issue.

Azure secret portal:

[image: azure secret portal]

https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python/issues/196

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30350393)